# Missing number, treated as zero (\hspace, I think)

Tags: errors, compilation-error, syntax, rmarkdown

At the outset let me say I am not even a LaTeX beginner - I know almost nothing. I have an .tex file named title.tex which was developed on a Windows platform and is used in an R markdown document like so:

```
output:
  pdf_document:
    latex_engine: xelatex
    includes:
      in_header: "preamble.tex"
      before_body: "title.tex"
```

This works for the person who created it on their windows laptop, but not in my Ubuntu system. The output/error I get is:

```
output file: template_vF.knit.md

/usr/lib/rstudio-server/bin/pandoc/pandoc +RTS -K512m -RTS template_vF.knit.md --to latex --from markdown+autolink_bare_uris+tex_math_single_backslash --output template_vF.tex --lua-filter /usr/local/lib/R/site-library/rmarkdown/rmarkdown/lua/pagebreak.lua --lua-filter /usr/local/lib/R/site-library/rmarkdown/rmarkdown/lua/latex-div.lua --self-contained --highlight-style tango --pdf-engine xelatex --include-in-header preamble.tex --include-before-body title.tex --variable graphics 
! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again> 
                   \vrule 
l.138 ...\hspace{25pt}\color{gray}\line(1,0){30pt}
                                                   \par 

Error: LaTeX failed to compile template_vF.tex. See https://yihui.org/tinytex/r/#debugging for debugging tips. See template_vF.log for more info.
```

I comment out that line specified in the output and it leads to another error. It seems like a syntax issue with `\hspace` but from my checking to the best of my ability, i seem to be using that method correctly. Is there anything obviously wrong in the below title.tex? Looking for help/hints.

title.tex below:

```
\begin{titlepage}
%Change margins for title page
    \newgeometry{top=.5cm,bottom=0cm, left=0cm, right = 0cm}

%Import header and footer/but remove footer
    \thispagestyle{fancy}
    \fancyfoot{}

%Set up left side of page
   \begin{minipage}{0.4\textwidth}
%Change to sans serif LaTeX font
    \sffamily
%Vertical space between top of page and logo
   \vspace*{50pt}
%Indent and insert logo
   \hspace{25pt}\includegraphics{logo.png} \par
%Vertical space between logo and Title
   \vspace*{150pt}
%Indent and title text
    \hspace{25pt}\Huge \textbf{A Huge Title} \par
    \vspace*{25pt}
\hspace{25pt} \color{bluefont}\LARGE A large subtitle... \par
\vspace*{1pt}
\hspace{25pt} ...continuing below \par
    \vspace*{15pt} 
%Divider line
    \hspace{25pt}\color{gray}\line(1,0){30pt} \par
%Indent and date
    \hspace{25pt}\color{black}\textbf{April 21, 2021}

    \end{minipage}%
\hfill
%Set up right half of page
    \begin{minipage}[t]{0.6\textwidth}
%Move image anchor to top of header
    \vspace*{-200pt}
%Insert cover photo
    \includegraphics[width = \textwidth]{cover.jpg}
    \vspace{-5pt}
%Change to sans serif LaTeX font
    \sffamily
%Create black box below image
%Current height is set to 220pt; increase if new photo causes gap at bottom
%Text and copy right on right hand title
    \colorbox{footergray}{\makebox(\textheight,220pt)[l]{\vspace{-50pt}\parbox[l]{\textheight}{\hspace{15pt}\Large \color{white}\textbf{Team Name} \par
    \vspace{15pt}\hspace{15pt}\large Person 1 Name \par
    \vspace{15pt}\hspace{15pt}\large Person 2 Name  \par 
    \vspace{50pt}
    \hspace{.55\textwidth}\copyright Company Name}}}
  \end{minipage}

    
\end{titlepage}
```

**EDIT 1:**
Here is preamble.tex:

```
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[letterpaper,top=1.25 cm,bottom=1cm,left=0cm,right=0cm,marginparwidth=0cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{booktabs}

% Define color for top bar
\definecolor{headergray}{RGB}{202, 215, 222}

% Define color for bottom bar
\definecolor{footergray}{RGB}{37, 39, 41}

% Define color for blue font
\definecolor{bluefont}{RGB}{66, 109, 155}

% Define color for table border
\definecolor{bordercolor}{RGB}{21, 147, 134}

% Create top bar colorbox
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\setlength{\headheight}{20pt}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}% Remove header/footer
\lhead{\setlength{\fboxsep}{5pt}\colorbox{headergray}{%
  \makebox[\dimexpr\linewidth-2pt][l]{\color{headergray}1
    \hfill
  }%
}}

% Create bottom bar colorbox
\lfoot{\setlength{\fboxsep}{10pt}\colorbox{footergray}{%
  \makebox[\dimexpr\linewidth-10pt][l]{\color{white} \sffamily
  \hspace{10pt} Footer Left Text
    \hfill
    \copyright \hspace{3pt} Footer Right Text\hspace{15pt}
    \textbf{\thepage} \hspace{15pt}
  }
  }}

\setlength{\headheight}{0pt}
```

**EDIT 2:**

```
xelatex --version
XeTeX 3.14159265-2.6-0.999991 (TeX Live 2019/Debian)
kpathsea version 6.3.1
```

**Edit 3:** (adding .Rmd - `rmarkdown::render("template_mwe.Rmd")`)

````
---
output:
  pdf_document:
    latex_engine: xelatex
    includes:
      in_header: "preamble.tex"
      before_body: "title.tex"
documentclass: report
classoption:
  - landscape
---


```{=latex}
%Change font style
\setmainfont{Arial} 

%Restore templated margins
\restoregeometry

% Add page title and logo to top
\setcounter{page}{2} 
\vspace*{10pt}
\hspace{20pt} \Huge Lay of the Land 
\large \color{bluefont} Quarterly Figures
\hfill \includegraphics{logo.png} \hspace{20pt}
\vspace*{20pt}

% Set line colors/thickness on tables
\arrayrulecolor{bordercolor}
\setlength{\arrayrulewidth}{1.5pt}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0pt}
```


```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE)
options(knitr.table.format = "latex")
options(knitr.kable.NA = "-")
#Import libraries
library(readr)
library(dplyr)
library(magrittr)
library(scales)
library(kableExtra)
library(tidyverse)
```


```{r, echo = FALSE}
### Import data
# f <- file.choose()
mpbqdat <- data.frame(t = rep(c(LETTERS[1:20], letters[1:20]), 4)) %>%
  arrange(t) %>%
  mutate(
    q = rep(c("I", "II", "III", "IV"), 40),
    mean = rnorm(160),
    med = rnorm(160),
    min = rnorm(160),
    max = rnorm(160))
```

\fontspec{Arial}
```{r}
#Color cell font/background based on rank in group
color_rows <- function(x) {
  sgn <- (x > 0)*1 + 1
  rnk <- rank(x, ties.method = "first", na.last = "keep")
  cell_spec(x, align = "c",
            color = case_when(is.na(sgn) ~ "black",
                              TRUE ~ c("#ff1342", "#126667")[sgn]),
            background = case_when(is.na(rnk) ~ "white",
                                   TRUE ~ c("#ffc8d1", "#ffe4e8", "#edfdfb", "#68eadd")[rnk])
  )
}

#Select and color mean q
meanq <- 
  mpbqdat %>%
  select(t, q, mean) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = q,
              values_from = mean) %>%
  column_to_rownames("t") %>%
  mutate(across(everything(), function(x) scales::percent(x, accuracy = .01))) %>%
  apply(., 1, color_rows)

#Select and color median q
medianq <-
  mpbqdat %>%
  select(t, q, med) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = q,
              values_from = med) %>%
  column_to_rownames("t") %>%
  mutate(across(everything(), function(x) scales::percent(x, accuracy = .01))) %>%
  apply(., 1, color_rows)

#Select and color max q
maxQtr <- mpbqdat %>%
  select(t, q, max) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = q,
              values_from = max) %>%
  select(-t) %>%
  mutate(across(everything(), function(x) scales::percent(x, accuracy = .01))) %>%
  apply(., 1, color_rows)

#Select and color min q
minQtr <- mpbqdat %>%
  select(t, q, min) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = q,
              values_from = min) %>%
  select(-t) %>%
  mutate(across(everything(), function(x) scales::percent(x, accuracy = .01))) %>%
  apply(., 1, color_rows)

#Create double spacer column for output spacing
blankRow <- rep("",ncol(meanq))
blankRow <- rbind(blankRow, blankRow)

#Combine qs with spacer rows for final output
output <- rbind(meanq,blankRow)
output <- rbind(output,medianq)
output <- rbind(output,blankRow)
output <- rbind(output, maxQtr)
output <- rbind(output, blankRow)
output <- rbind(output, minQtr)
output <- rbind(output, blankRow)

#Rename columns based on qs
rownames(output) = c("I", "II","III","IV", "",
                     "", "I", "II","III","IV", "",
                     "", "I", "II","III","IV", "",
                     "", "I", "II","III","IV","",""
)

#Add spacer rows between ts at given freq
freq <- 12
skips <- floor(ncol(output)/freq)

for (i in 1:skips) {
  output <- cbind(output[,1:(freq*i+(i-1))],"",output[,(freq*i+i):ncol(output)])
}

#Add spacer rows at top and bottom of output
output <- cbind(output[,0],"",output[,1:ncol(output)])
output <- cbind(output[,1:ncol(output)],"")

#Convert output to list to be able to use in Kable
tablePrep <- list(
  output %>%
    t()
) 

#Create Kable contruct
kable(tablePrep, format = "latex",
      escape = FALSE,
      longtable = FALSE,
      booktabs = TRUE,
      linesep = "") %>%
  
  #Create custom styling on final outputted table
  #font_size - change font size across whole table
  
  kable_styling(font_size = 6.75,
                full_width = FALSE,
                latex_options = "HOLD_position", position = "center") %>%
  
  #add_header_above - add/format header for q labels
  add_header_above(c(" "=1, "q" = 4, " "=2, "q" = 4, " "=2, "q" = 4, " "=2, "q" = 4," "=2), color = "#0E635A", align = "l", bold = TRUE) %>%
  
  #add_header_above - add/format header for mean/med/min/max labels 
  add_header_above(c(" "=1, "AVERAGE RETURN" = 4, " "=2, "MEDIAN RETURN" = 4, " "=2, "MAX RETURN" = 4, " "=2, "MIN RETURN" = 4, " "=2),background = c("white","#558A9B"), color = "white", line = FALSE, align = "l", bold = TRUE) %>%
  
  #row_spec - format I/II/III/IV header row
  
  row_spec(0, align = "c", bold = TRUE, color = "#558A9B", hline_after = FALSE)%>%
  
  #Remove default horizontal lines running full length of table
  sub("\\\\toprule", "", .) %>%
  sub("\\\\midrule", "", .) %>%
  sub("\\\\bottomrule", "", .) %>%
  
  #Set width of t column
  column_spec(1, width = "1.4cm")%>%
  
  #Set width of data columns and left borders
  column_spec(c(2:5,8:11,14:17,20:23), width = "1.46cm") %>%
  column_spec(c(2,8,14,20), width = "1.46cm", border_left = TRUE)%>%
  
  #Set right borders via dummy spacer columns
  column_spec(c(6,12,18,24), width_min = "0pt", width = "0pt", border_right = TRUE) %>%
  
  #Set width of spacer columns
  column_spec(c(7,13,19), width = ".6cm") %>%
  
  #Add bottom borders
  row_spec(ncol(output), extra_latex_after = "\\cline{2-5} \\cline{8-11} \\cline{14-17} \\cline{20-23}")%>%
  
  #Add top borders
  row_spec(0, extra_latex_after = "\\cline{2-5} \\cline{8-11} \\cline{14-17} \\cline{20-23}")
  ```
````

**EDIT 4:** (generated TeX from R markdown)
[Uploaded to google drive due to length](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1wZJiKCu9WTwqTJz7qj2Ko_fbjERFktqx/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: When I substitute generic images for your graphics and generic colors for your colors, it compiles just fine for me.  Therefore, you will need to provide a (non-)working example of code that begins with `\documentclass` and ends with `\end{document}`

Comment: it would be useful to provide teh generated latex rather than the R source, most of us don't have R, hower as pointed out in the answer the issue is the \makebox syntax,

Comment: @DavidCarlisle makes sense, sorry about that. See Edit 4

Comment: the problem exists even after modifying the \makebox syntax (replacing parens w/ curlybraces)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While the answers above helped and taught me some new things, I solved this after 10 hours by changing

```
%Divider line
\hspace{25pt}\color{gray}\line(1,0){30pt} \par
```

to

```
%Divider line
\hspace{25pt}\color{gray}\line(1,0){30} \par
```

Comment: Accept the answer that solved your answer. [What is "accepting"? and what to do when I answered myself?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/1041018)

Comment: Need to wait 2 days, cus it is my answer

Comment: Needless to say, I didn't specify a time, I knew the limit and thought about this, Happy LaTeX!

Comment: You have an old latex (older than the 2020-10-01 release)

Answer (score 0):

### Solution

On `xelatex` I got the same error the original post had.

First step was to reconstitute a `mwe.tex`

Second step was a typo in the original:

Old:

```
    \colorbox{footergray}{\makebox(\textheight,220pt)[l]
{\vspace{-50pt}\parbox[l]{\textheight}{\hspace{15pt}\Large 
\color{white}\textbf{Team Name} \par
```

New:

```
    \colorbox{footergray}{\makebox{\textheight,220pt}[l]
\vspace{-50pt}\parbox[l]{\textheight}{\hspace{15pt}\Large
\color{white}\textbf{Team Name} \par
```

The typo was `\makebox` argument for this marking goes into braces `{ ... }` rather than parentheses  `( ... )`

There are other nits to pick in the original, but not relevant to to the problem at hand.

The differences outlined above should unblock you.

The error you were chasing was occurring further up the document.

### Environment

```
$ xelatex --version
XeTeX 3.14159265-2.6-0.99998 (TeX Live 2017/Debian)
kpathsea version 6.2.3
```

### MWE

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[letterpaper,
            top=1.25 cm,
            bottom=1cm,
            left=0cm,
            right=0cm,
            marginparwidth=0cm]{geometry}

\definecolor{headergray}{RGB}{202, 215, 222}
\definecolor{footergray}{RGB}{37, 39, 41}
\definecolor{bluefont}{RGB}{66, 109, 155}
\definecolor{bordercolor}{RGB}{21, 147, 134}

% Create top bar colorbox
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\setlength{\headheight}{20pt}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}% Remove header/footer
\lhead{\setlength{\fboxsep}{5pt}\colorbox{headergray}{%
  \makebox[\dimexpr\linewidth-2pt][l]{\color{headergray}1
    \hfill
  }%
}}

% Create bottom bar colorbox
\lfoot{\setlength{\fboxsep}{10pt}\colorbox{footergray}{%
  \makebox[\dimexpr\linewidth-10pt][l]{\color{white} \sffamily
  \hspace{10pt} Footer Left Text
    \hfill
    \copyright \hspace{3pt} Footer Right Text\hspace{15pt}
    \textbf{\thepage} \hspace{15pt}
  }
  }}

\setlength{\headheight}{0pt}

\begin{document}

\begin{titlepage}
\newgeometry{top=.5cm,bottom=0cm, left=0cm, right = 0cm}
\thispagestyle{fancy}
\fancyfoot{}

\begin{minipage}{0.4\textwidth}
\sffamily
\vspace*{50pt}
\hspace{25pt}\includegraphics{logo.png} \par
\vspace*{150pt}
\hspace{25pt}\Huge \textbf{A Huge Title} \par
\vspace*{25pt}
\hspace{25pt} \color{bluefont}\LARGE A large subtitle... \par
\vspace*{1pt}
\hspace{25pt} ...continuing below \par
\vspace*{15pt} 
\hspace{25pt}
\color{gray}
\line(1,0) {30}
\par
\hspace{25pt}\color{black}\textbf{April 21, 2021}
\end{minipage}

\hfill

\begin{minipage}[t]{0.6\textwidth}
\vspace*{-200pt}
\includegraphics[width = \textwidth]{cover.jpg}
\vspace{-5pt}
\sffamily

\colorbox{footergray}{%
   \makebox{\textheight,220pt}[l]{%
     \vspace{-50pt}\parbox[l]{%
          \textheight}{%
              \hspace{15pt}\Large \color{white}\textbf{Team Name} \par
              \vspace{15pt}\hspace{15pt}\large Person 1 Name \par
              \vspace{15pt}\hspace{15pt}\large Person 2 Name  \par 
              \vspace{50pt}
              \hspace{0.55\textwidth}
              \copyright\ Company Name}}}

\end{minipage}
\end{titlepage}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Appreciate the help and sorry I forgot about the png/jpg.
I changed the parens to curl braces where indicated for \makebox. I'm still getting the same error tho unfortunately. Were any of the other nits potentially relevant? And is it not strange that it worked with the parens on the other system?

xelatex --version
XeTeX 3.14159265-2.6-0.999991 (TeX Live 2019/Debian)
kpathsea version 6.3.1

Comment: The missing graphics isn't that much of a show-stopper.  Still getting an error eh?  Hmm.  So I'll update my answer with the `mwe.tex` (minimum working example).  And I'll suggest that you start forming  **your minimum failing example** so all can take a look.    Remember to make it a complete document (see comments above about it begins with `\documentclass...` and ending with `\end{document}`)

Comment: sorry this answer is incorrect. the form with `{}` can not take a comma separated pair.  @mb158127 the picture mode form could only take numbers (multiples of `\unitlength` )not lengths until the latex release 202-10-01

Comment: but despite this thanks for making an example despite the lack of a usable test in the question

Comment: @DavidCarlisle  I see your point.  Odd that my `xelatex` accepted `\makebox{h,w} ...`

Comment: ok, turns out I can render mwe.tex using the command >xelatex mwe.tex . That is true with the { } form for makebox; I get an error using (). The problem seems to be then something about the R/Rmarkdown environment that I am trying to render from in reality. This is also the reason I did not have/know about a mwe latex doc - it is provided in pieces to my Rmd... I think my question may need to go to SO instead.

Comment: @jdw it's  not that ncommon that incorrect syntax just "drops through" error detection in a macro expansion language is "interesting"

Comment: @mb158127 S.O.  would bounce it here. the `\makebox(\textheight,200pt` form requires eithe a current latex or use the `picture` package to use a similarly extended version of picture mode on older latex

Comment: @jdw updating the OP with my mnwe Rmd, title.tex, and preamble.tex
Should constitute a mnwe (assume based on comment you are OK using some example logo.png and cover.jpg images already)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle too - hope I included everything needed in Edit 3 above. Save everything in same working directory. If you need a logo.png/cover.jpg let me know or any small logo, medium size cover image should work... lmk if you need other environment info